# Question about Universal Mapping Property

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Now I seem to understand the construction of the tensor product of $R$-Modules by defining $$F_R(M \times N) := \bigoplus_{(m,n) \in M \times N} R\delta_{(m,n)}$$
and constructing the submodule $D$ in a manner such that $\otimes: M \times N \to M \otimes N = F_R(M \times N)\, / \, D$ is bilinear and thus by the universal mapping property, we can find $\ell \circ M = B$ where $M: (m,n) \to \delta_{(m,n)}$, $B: M \times N \to P$, $P$ being some $R$-module. And since we can show that $D \subseteq \ker{\ell}$ and $\ell$ is linear, then given $\otimes$, we may essentially disregard the submodule $D$ and have $\ell \circ \otimes = B$ and thus the tensor product admits a unique linear map $\ell$.

Now my question is as follows:

Does someone have a proof of why there exists a property such that this linear map must exist, I understand how everything works if this property is true. But why and when is it true?

My other question is why is it necessary to construct the tensor product at all? Why can't we just construct $F_R$ and use the linear map from it to $P$? Is it because we want the properties that come along with modding out $D$?

Comment: Is $R$ commutative? Otherwise I don't see how $M\otimes_RN$ is an $R$-module. Have you *tried* to prove the universal property? That is, given any bilinear $f:M\times N\to P$, it can be factored through $\otimes$, and that the map $M\otimes N\to P$ is uniquely determined by $P$? The free module on $M\times N$ is way too big, it has way too much redundancy in it (look how big $D$ is!), and one would have to forget the purpose of $\otimes$ in the first splace: as a universal way station between two modules and their bilinear targets, and to extend scalars with "pretend" multiplication.

Comment: @blue Yes, $R$ is commutative. I do not know how to prove existence, but I do know how to prove uniqueness..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume $R$ is commutative so $M\otimes_RN$ is an $R$-module.

The elements of $M\otimes_RN$ look like sums of pure tensors of the form $m\otimes n$ with $m\in M,n\in N$, modulo the relations that describe bilinearity of the $\otimes$ symbol. The $R$-module structure of the tensor product is defined by $r(m\otimes n)=rm\otimes n$ (which equals $m\otimes rn$). In order to construct this module formally, we have to quotient the free module on the Cartesian product as we do.

One checks the map $\otimes:M\times N\to M\otimes_RN$ given by $(m,n)\mapsto m\otimes n$ is bilinear. Suppose we have any other bilinear map $f:M\times N\to P$ and we want to find out if it can be factored as

$$M\times N\xrightarrow{\otimes}M\otimes_RN\xrightarrow{\tilde{f}}P.$$

Necessarily $\tilde{f}(m\otimes n)=f(m,n)$, so $\tilde{f}$ is uniquely determined by $f$. One also checks that the map defined by this equality (namely $\tilde{f}(m\otimes n)=f(m,n)$) is a well-defined $R$-module morphism.

Why not just use the free module on the Cartesian product? Because it's big, unwieldy, it has too much redundancy. We want things as tight as possible; it's a sort of "minimal information needed to specify" situation. Any $R$-module homomorphism is determined by where it sends the elements in a chosen generating set. The generating set of $F_R(M\times N)$ is all of $M\times N$, and the information of $f(m,n)$ for all $(m,n)\in M\times N$ is *way, way more information than we need*. Somehow we need to make it tighter in order to remove all of the ugly redundancy. The tensor product achieves that; any bilinear map $f:M\times N\to P$ is determined by where it sends the elements of a generating set of the module $M\otimes_RN$.

Indeed, if one wants to find a universal "way station" through which all bilinear maps factor through, one needs this $R$-module to be generated by the images of all the $(m,n)\in M\times N$, and hence contain their sums as well, but must be subject to bilinearity since the map from $M\times N$ to this way station needs to be bilinear. This exactly characterizes what $M\otimes_RN$ is!

The tensor product, and its universal property, is extremely useful. Multilinear maps become linear maps, hom spaces can be rearranged with tensor-hom adjunction, scalars can be extended.

Comment: Wonderful answer and exposition. I understand everything except why it is that $\tilde{f}$ is guaranteed to be linear.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter In order to define a linear map it suffices to define where a generating set is sent to. Since pure tensors are a generating set for $M\otimes_RN$, and we've defined where $\tilde{f}$ sends pure tensors $m\otimes n$, we extend with linearity to define $\tilde{f}$ on all of $M\otimes_RN$. Defining a linear map by simply specifying where it sends generators is a rather ubiquitous practice in mathematics.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you. I don't quite have the maturity for these things yet, being a sophomore in high school. Excuse the inherent ignorance.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter No problem. The real issue is not linearity of $\tilde{f}$, which is inherent, but its *well-definedness*. A tensor may have two different representations as sums of pure tensors, and $\tilde{f}$ is defined by the representation of a tensor as a sum of pure tensors, so we need to check it doesn't depend on *which* representation. Since all distinct representations of a tensor as sums of pure tensors come from using the bilinearity relations for the symbol $\otimes$, it suffices to check $$f((m'+m)\otimes n)=f(m'\otimes n+m\otimes n)$$ and the same on the other side of $\otimes$.

Comment: And also $f(rm\otimes n)=f(m\otimes rn)$, but that wouldn't fit in by above comment because of character limits.